# test .ts class by node-tap

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nestjs, tap

I have a class :
company-class.ts

```
export class CompanyRequest {
        async getCompanies(): Promise<any> {
        const result= await this.request(this.reqBody);

        return result;
    }

}
```

I use node-tap for testing
mytest.ts

```
import { CompanyRequest } from "../src/Requests/company-requests";
const tap = require('tap')
tap.test('get compmies', async t => {  
  const req = new CompanyRequest();
  const res = await req.getCompanies();
  t.equal(0,0);
})
```

Finally, I get this error
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

If not use Company Request test is true, like this

```
const tap = require('tap')
tap.test('get compmies', async t => {  
  t.equal(0,0);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install tap globally: npm i -g tap
after that, put this code on package.json

```
"test": "tap --node-arg=--require=ts-node/register",
```

run => npm run test